# Delete using NOT IN clause in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a table **issue_assigned** having user_id as Integer and issue number as Varchar. The issues can be assigned to multiple users.

Now there is a condition if the issue is previously assigned to 3 users and then admin wants to assign it only to 2 users, The system should delete the 3rd user entry for that I wrote following code

```
String hql = "delete from issueAssigned  where issueNumber=:issueNum AND assignedToUserId not in (:userIds)";
Query query = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("issueNum", issueNum);
query.setParameter("userIds", userIds);
if(query.executeUpdate() > 0){
    return "success";
}else{
    return "error";
}
```

userIds is a string which contain userId seperated by comma(,). When executed I get String cannot be caste to integer error.

How can i keep the required users and delete rest? What changes I will have to do?

Answer (score 2):

> userIds is a string which contain userId seperated by comma(,)

It shouldn't be. You should just pass an array or collection of user IDs. Hibernate will create the corresponding SQL prepared statement for you, by adding a parameter placeholder for each user ID.

And the parentheses around `:userIds` aren't needed either.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `setParameter` which take only one parameter you have to use [**`setParameterList`**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection)) which take a **Collection** of parameters not **String** :

```
query.setParameterList("userIds", userIds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query will be

```
String hql = "delete from issue_assigned  where issue_number=:issueNum AND assigned_to_user_id not in :userIds";
```

and use  query.setParameterList as follows

```
 query.setParameterList("userIds", userIds);
```

hibernate will create the prepared statement using the collection passed.